# Implementing notification for Android 26 using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Im using Delphi 10.1 for developing android application and I  have used the [Delphi sample](https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/05/targeting-android-8-and-higher/) for implementing Android 26 API and when I have used notification, it does not display. And also I have tried with the [Notification example](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/Notifications). But it does not works. Please help me to implement the notification as I need to implement this from Android services.

```
procedure TForm1.ImmediateNotification; 
var 
LNotification: TNotification; 
begin 
LNotification.EnableSound := False;
 LNotification.Title := 'Immediate Notification';
 LNotification.Subtitle := 'Subtitles are cool';
 LNotification.AlertBody := 'This is an immediate notification'; 
FNotifications.PresentNotification(LNotification); 
end;
```

Comment: Could you put your notification code?

Comment: Yes . I have tried with both system.notification and also Dw.notification

Comment: No no, you don't understand, I'd like you to show me your code, put up the function of the notification in your description.

Comment: The article in first link you gave has been superseded by this one: https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/06/targeting-android-8-and-higher-continued, however the article and particularly the changes to System.Android.Notification are for Delphi 10.2.3 only. You would need to work out the corresponding changes for Delphi 10.1. It might be easier to change to Delphi 10.3.1

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FMX.Android_Notification_Service_Sample I have used this, but it's not working.

Comment: I edited your description to put your code in there

Comment: The answer which you have mentioned also does not works

Comment: You are making life really hard for yourself by using Delphi 10.1. For one thing, I'm fairly sure that attempting to use notifications in a service with that version simply will not work, let alone attempting to target API 26+, which would need a bunch of changes to the Delphi source files. Is there a *good* reason why you're unable to use Delphi 10.3.1?

Comment: If I'm using Delphi 10.3, will the notification supports?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you aren't responsive, I'm going on a whim here, I've put my notification code up for you, to implement it with Android Service, you should check out: [This from the DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FMX.Android_Notification_Service_Sample)

```
procedure TF_SS_MAIN.NotifyAndroid(text: string);
var
   Notification: TNotification;
begin
{verify if the service is actually supported}
if NotificationCenter1.Supported then
   begin
   Notification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
   Notification.Name := 'Notif Name';
   Notification.AlertBody := text;
   Notification.FireDate := Now;

   {Send notification in Notification Center}
   NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(Notification);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: That's not going to work when targeting API 26+, using Delphi 10.1, as Developer said they are using.

Comment: @DaveNottage I have Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and I have used the method to target API26+, and it works for me. By doing the method to Target API 26+ has given me some problems for example the camera doesn't work for Android 6+, but all in all it works

Comment: There is no way using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, without modification of the source, that a notification will show when setting targetSdkVersion is set to 26+ on a device that has Android 8 or above. It *must* assign a channel (which does not happen with Delphi 10.1), otherwise it simply will not show. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels